# Does the time change on thin clients to sync up to what application say the time is?

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, logging, event-viewer, events

I know this question is not put the best way and I can edit it to read better after I have a better understanding of this. We are using a Windows 10 Enterprise environment that is VMI and VDI based. Basically, what I'm seeing is that there are multiple errors that occur on the system log that occur with the application log as well. The theory of thought we are exploring is that the VDI reaches out to the domain controller and gets the time and pulls that back, but when the application starts it tells the VDI that the time is incorrect the the time the application has is the correct one. When that happens it creates these errors we are seeing. Can anyone help clarify whether this is a valid theory or provide another explanation as to why this is occurring?

[Event Viewer Logs Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3BF2.png)

Comment: What are the reasons you believe the application has its own internal clock that may be conflicting with the computer clock? Those errors you've posted don't seen to indicate any real problems at this moment.

Comment: @music2myear I didn't see a problem either other than the certificate errors. That error is "Automatic certificate enrollment for local system failed (0x80070576) There is a time and/or date difference between the client and server." I was asked this question, posed as a theory. It didn't make sense to me and I don't see that in the event logs. I just wanted to post this question to see if anyone else had experienced anything like that.

Comment: What is the time difference? What is the NTP setup on the network? Is the network's CA pulling from the same time server?

Comment: Yes, this was the problem. Some machines were configured incorrectly and our network team resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When diagnosing time-related issues in a network, especially where two different systems generate errors because their internal clocks do not agree, the root issue is likely that the overall network time configuration is not consistent.

Either one or more of the systems are not getting time from the same source, or the source is not functioning.

Confirming correct time config on each of the systems on the network and correct function of the NTP host is a key first step for diagnosing and resolving such issues.